# When building from source where is golemsp is located at?

Tags: yagna

I tried following this [guide](https://handbook.golem.network/see-also/running-yagna-from-sources) to compile golem from source but I don't see golemsp in any of the output folders. Do I have do something specific to compile golemsp and its necessary binaries also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
cargo build --workspace
```

to build all binaries or

```
cargo build -p golemsp
```

to build only `golemsp` which will be much faster than building all.